# Чи можна вважати "магазин" русизмом?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм

"Магазин" є в Сучаному тлумачному словнику української мови і, загалом, вважається синонімом "крамниці". Але знайшла роздум, що слово «магазин» частіше вживалося в українській мові у значенні «склад»: «На самім кінці Борислава... стояв великий магазин, де складували земний віск» (І. Франко) та ін. Під впливом російської мови це слово почали широко вживати в розумінні «крамниця». При чому, "крамниця" взагалі досить рідко вживають...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Згідно з [Б. Д. Антоненко-Давидовичем](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/mahazyn-kramnycya-kramnychka) — магазин, то більше синонім до слова комора.

> #### §33. Магазин, крамниця, крамничка
>
> У сучаснiй українськiй офiцiйнiй i дiловiй мовi слово *магазин* замiнило всi iншi синонiми, широко вiдомi в класичнiй лiтературi й живому мовленнi, де, якщо й траплялося слово *магазин* (або *гамазин*, *гамазей*, *гамазея*, *гамазiя*), то далеко в вужчому значеннi. Цi слова означали не будiвлю для продажу, а велику комору на зерно („Пiдпалюють *гамазини* з хлiбом“. — О. Стороженко ) або комору на рiзне начиння, знаряддя, продукти („Рушниць, мушкетiв, оружжин наклали повнi *гамазеї*“. — I. Котляревський; „На самiм кiнцi Борислава... стояв великий *магазин*, де складували земний вiск“. — I. Франко).
>
> Заклад, де продають харчi або якiсь iншi припаси й речi, незалежно вiд розмiру його й асортименту краму, в класичнiй лiтературi й народнiй мовi називали й називають *крамницею*: „Завiв *крамницю* з тютюном“ (I. Нечуй‑Левицький); „Ще сонце не зайшло, а вже *крамницi* почали зачинятись“ (М. Коцюбинський); „Лелiя спинилась бiля одної дуже великої *крамницi*, там в освiтленому вiкнi стояло багато квiтiв“ (Леся Українка). Крамницi, де продають спецiальнi вироби, мають теж свої назви: *книгарня*, де продають лiтературу, *цукерня*, де продають солодощi, тощо („Перед дверима *цукернi* ще помацався за кишеню, чи є грошi“. — Л. Мартович).
>
> Якщо мовиться про дрiбну сiльську крамницю, вживають зменшеного iменника — *крамничка*, вiдповiдно до росiйського слова *лавка*: „Якiв зайшов до кума в *крамничку*“ (Марко Вовчок).
>
> Навряд чи є потреба замiняти всi цi слова одним-однiсiньким словом
>   *магазин*, бо таким способом збiднюється багата на рiзноманiтну лексику
>   українська мова.

Answer (score 3):

Вікіпедія переадресовує на [Крамницю](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F), проте дає варіант **магазин** як додатковий.

> Магазин — об'єкт торгівлі, розташований в окремій капітальній споруді
>   або приміщеннях іншої капітальної споруди або тимчасової споруди
>   некапітального типу або їх частинах

Натомість у нас є свій термін **крамниця**, який не є русизмом.

А ось щодо походження:

> Слово «магазин» утворено від арабського слова, яке у множині означає
>   «комори», «склади». У цьому ж сенсі це слово потрапило з французької
>   мови (magasin, magazin) в українську. Поступово змінило своє смислове
>   навантаження, витіснивши слово «лавка».

Тож так, це не стільки русизм, скільки запозичене слово, але загальновживане. Як і маркет.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Доповнення [до](/a/3648/585) про походження*</sub>

## [ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf)

> **крам** «предмет торгівлі (звичайнофабричного виробництва), товар», *кра­мар*, *крамаренко*, *крамариха*, *крама­рівна*, [***крамарня***] «крамниця» Г, Ж, *крамарство*, *крамарчук*, [*крамарщик*] «крамар» Л, [*крамарщина*] «дрібний то­вар» Ж. [*крамщина*] «тс.» Ж. [*крамина, крамнина*] «тканина фабричного вироб­ництва», крамниця, [*крамарний*] «тор­говий» Я, *крамарський, крамний, крам­ничний*, [*крамовий*] «крамний», [*крам­ський*] «тс.», *крамарювати, крамува­ти*, ст. *крамъ* (1460), *крамныи* (1388);
>
> російська [*крам*] «дрібний товар», білоруська *крама* «лавка, крамниця», ст. *крамъ* (1582), крамныи (1338), польська kram «крамниця; (ст.) крам», чеська, словацька krám «крамниця», вл. klamy «тс.», нл. kšamy «дрібні товари; крамниця», ст. kramy «тс.», полаб. krom «крам», слн. krâm «крамар­ські товари»;
>
> запозичення з німець­кої мови, можливо, частково за поль­ським посередництвом; свн. krām(e) «крамниця, ятка; розіслане сукно, то­вар», двн. crām «ятка», снн. krām(e) «полотняна покрівля ятки», тол. kraam «крам; крамниця» походять від пгерм. *krama- «покрівля, яку мандрівні купці напинали над своїм возом»; спроба ви­вести п. kram з пд.‑сл. *храм* (Brückner 264; Веrn. І 606) безпідставна.
>
> ---
>
> **магазин** «крамниця; комора; склад; частина апарата або приладу (найчастіше зброї); [додаткові рамки у вулику ЛексПол]», [*магазин*] «колгоспна ко­мора» Па, [*магазін*] «магазин; колгоспне приміщення для зерна, амбар; скляний резервуар лампи, в який наливають гас» Л, [*маказин*] «колгоспне примі­щення для зерна, амбар» Л, Па, *магази­нер* «власник крамниці; продавець у крамниці», *магазинка* «рушниця з мага­зином», *магазинник* «комірник»;
>
> російська, болгарська *магазин*, білоруська *магазін*, польська magazyn «магазин; ілюстрований журнал», чеська словацька magazin «універмаг; ілюстрований жур­нал», вл. magacin «магазин, склад, депо», македонська *магазин* «склад, магазин; журнал», схв. магазӣн, магацӣн «тс.», слн. magazín «склад; депо; магазин»;
>
> через по­середництво західноєвропейських мов (нім. Magazín, фр. magasin, іт. maggazzino «магазин, склад», пор. також ісп. ст. magacén «тс.») запозичено з арабської; араб. mahā́zin є формою множини від mahzū́n «склад», похідного від házaпa «він зібрав, нагромадив»